# openpyxl load_workbook() freezes

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to use `wb = load_workbook(filename)` but either I work in Python console or call it from a script, it hangs for a while, then my laptop completely freezes. I can't switch to console to reboot, can't restart X etc. (UPD: CPU consumption is 100% in this moment, memory consump. is 5% only). Has anybody met such issue?

Python 2.7, openpyxl 2.4.9

Comment: Does this happen with all Excel files? Which OS are you using?

Comment: what Max above me asks, plus, how large is the file you're trying to parse, and what is it's source (trusted/ internet)?

Comment: @omu_negru  I am using Fedora 26, trying to open local (trusted) XLSM (containing macro inside) file which size is 1,2Mb and it has 5 sheets inside. no charts there but few images. Unfortunately it happens with every file I am trying to open

Answer (score 0):

The warning is exactly that, a warning about some aspect of the file being removed. But it has nothing to do with the rest of the question. I suspect you are running out of memory. How much memory is openpyxl using when the laptop freezes?

Comment: Thanks for uour reply, Charlie. Not sure why my question has been downvoted,  as I think its not the usual case. I have 16Gb of memory and I just have managed to note that memory consumption after running the script is 5% only - but CPU is busy on 100% according to top output.

Comment: Downvoted because your question is pretty much "why doesn't this work?"

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue kinda.... I had been editing my excel workbook. I ended up accidentally pasting a space  into an almost infinite amount of rows. ya know... like a lot. I selected all empty cells and hit delete, saved workbook, problem gone.

Comment: In the comments above OP said the size of the file is 1.2 MB. I find it hard to believe that's the issue